# Python elementree error when removing tags

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I have code like this for removing all tags named sysId from xml in root_compare function:

```
   #removing sysId from comparison
    for rm1 in xml_root1.findall('.//sysId'):
    xml_root1.remove(rm1)
```

The code gives me this error:

```
 File "/tmp/dev_uac_api2/uac_api_lib.py", line 105, in root_compare
    xml_root1.remove(rm1)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 337, in remove
    self._children.remove(element)
  ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I need to go through all elements in xml even child, grandchild and remove the ones called sysId. Can you help me solve this problem?

the xml structure is something like:

```
<root>
    <sysId></sysId>
    <b></b>
    <c>
        <sysId></sysId>
    </c>
    <d>
        <e>
            <sysId></sysId>
        </e>
    </d>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing elements is a little more work in ElementTree than it is in lxml because lxml has the `getparent()` function.

In ElementTree, you first need to match the parent of the element to remove.

[ElementTree's xpath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) isn't great either so `.//*[sysId]` isn't going to match the first `sysId` element since it's a direct child of the root element. You'll have to remove those separately.

Example...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """<root>
    <sysId></sysId>
    <b></b>
    <c>
        <sysId></sysId>
    </c>
    <d>
        <e>
            <sysId></sysId>
        </e>
    </d>
</root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

# find/remove direct "sysId" children of root
for child in root.findall("sysId"):
    root.remove(child)

# find elements that contain a "sysId" child element
for parent in root.findall(".//*[sysId]"):
    # find/remove direct "sysId" children of parent
    for child in parent.findall("sysId"):
        parent.remove(child)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Printed output...

```xml
<root>
    <b />
    <c>
        </c>
    <d>
        <e>
            </e>
    </d>
</root>
```

Here's an example of [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html) to show the difference (same printed output as above)...

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """<root>
    <sysId></sysId>
    <b></b>
    <c>
        <sysId></sysId>
    </c>
    <d>
        <e>
            <sysId></sysId>
        </e>
    </d>
</root>"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

for elem in root.xpath(".//sysId"):
    elem.getparent().remove(elem)

print etree.tostring(root)
```

Comment: Great! helped a lot. Thank you @Daniel Haley